# リモートVPNでパケットキャプチャを取得したい

Tags: network

以下の構成でリモートVPNを行っています。

[internet]-[ルータ]-[VPNルータ]-[NAS]

PCからNASのパケットキャプチャを取得したいのですが、VPNルータ側の機能で取得する以外に方法はありますか？

Comment: PC はインターネット (VPN) 越しに接続されるという認識であっていますか？

Comment: その認識であっております。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

いろいろ手はあります。
NASのパケットキャ機能（無い可能性は高いてすね）を利用する。
[VPNルータ]-[NAS]の間に、以下の機器とパソコンを接続してパケットキャプチャする。
・リピーターハブ
・ポートミラーリング機能を持っているスイッチングハブを接続して、NAS用のポートのミラーポートを作る